# Hive Create Table Reading CSV from S3 data spill

Tags: apache-spark, amazon-s3, hive

I’m trying to create a hive table from external location on S3 from a CSV file.

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE coder_bob_schema.my_table (column       data type)
ROW DELIMITED
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ‘,’
LOCATION ‘s3://mybucket/path/file.CSV’
```

The resultant table has data from n-x fields spilling over to n which leads me to believe Hive doesn’t like the CSV. However, I downloaded the CSV from s3 and it opens and looks okay in excel. Is there a workaround like using a different delimiter?

Comment: it shouldn't be, hive can easily ingest csv data. I am confused about the error. Is your table and file structure are identical ? if yes, try converting all columns to `string`, create the table and load data using `load data` command. if definition are different then you need to make them same to load the data.

Comment: Thanks, Roy. I realized I set an index and hive was pushing down all my other fields with the wrong data types.